# Should I use !important or not?

Tags: css

I often have this problem and am not sure of the most elegant solution. I don't want to use `!important` although that would work.

I have articles on my site which are contained in a div with the class `article`. The corresponding CSS controls the H4 tag like this.

```
.articles h4 {
font-size: 16px;
}
```

However within my articles I have a div element with the class `notice` which also has a number of H4 tags, but when I use this CSS below, the declaration from the `articles` class is applied instead.

```
.notice h4 {
font-size: 24px;
}
```

What I want is a solution that means I don't have to apply classes to the actual H4 tags in `notice` — I want to be able to point to H4 tags by their container element.

Comment: If the above works for you let me know and I'll post it as an answer so you can accept rather some of than the others below which have copied it.

Comment: see my issue below about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your mark up is something like this:

```
<div class="articles">
    <h4> Article Title </h4>
    <div class="notice">
        <h4> Notice Title </h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

As long as

```
.notice h4 {
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

is below .articles in your css file it should work. However, another fix would be to use

```
.articles .notice h4 {
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

Comment: I can't put it below it's in a different style sheet and see above for  second solution

Comment: Did you try changing the order you import the style sheets? E.G.

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/Articles.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/Notice.css" />

I think your problem is that you're importing the css for the articles after the notices, causing the font size to be overridden.

Comment: you are right but that's just how the files are set up and can't be changes, the notice class is site wide while the articles class is specific to a section of the site.

Comment: !important is the way to go then.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to target the class more specific. Try to use

```
.articles .notice h4 {
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

Comment: The trouble is notices can also be in other containers

Comment: then you might want to add a .othercontainer .notice h4 { font-size: 24px;} too.

Comment: The point is that notices will be in many different containers so I don't want to write a declaration for each situation.

Comment: In that case i would recomend using !important anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors). If your `.article` class is just a wrapper and the h4 element is a direct child of it, this is an easy fix. The child selector is [widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel2).

```
.article > h4 { font-size: 16px; }
```

The child selector will not apply any of its styles to an element that is not an immediate ancestor. So if you have another h4 element in another wrapper, it will not have the styles of the one outside the wrapper.

Comment: The style is still get overwritten

Comment: @user1209203 is the style even being applied, or did you copy/paste my code? My code might've been misspelled.

Comment: it was seen and over written, I have re-jigged my css and found a better way.